# Deck of Cards array, manipulated with functions, prints out error

Tags: python, c#, arrays, list, methods

Basically, my friend asked me to help with his c# mid-term exam. I agreed. He sent me all the questions and we solved all, except the last one. We kept on getting 80/100 points with no clue on what's wrong. It's not like in leetcode where they give the last executed input so we can debug the question with it. Just 'Incorrect Answer' error.

[Check the photos to examine the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaB4k.png)
[Example Input-Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvZTU.png)

This is how i coded it in python first

```
deck = input().split(', ')
n = int(input())


def add(deck,command):
    cardname = command[1]
    if cardname in deck:
        return 'Card is already in the deck'
    deck.append(cardname)
    return 'Card successfully added'


def remove(deck,command):
    cardname = command[1]
    if cardname in deck:
        deck.remove(cardname)
        return 'Card successfully removed'
    return 'Card not found'


def removeat(deck,command):
    index = int(command[1])
    if index not in range(len(deck)):
        return 'Index out of range'
    deck.pop(index)
    return 'Card successfully removed'


def insert(deck,command):
    index = int(command[1])
    cardname = command[2]
    if index not in range(len(deck)):
        return 'Index out of range'
    if cardname in deck and index in range(len(deck)):
        return 'Card is already in the deck'
    deck.insert(index,cardname)
    return 'Card successfully added'


for i in range(n):
    command = input().split(', ')
    if command[0]== 'Add' and len(command) ==2:
        print(add(deck,command))
    elif command[0]== 'Remove' and len(command) ==2:
        print(remove(deck,command))
    elif command[0]== 'Remove At'and len(command) ==2:
        print(removeat(deck,command))
    elif command[0]== 'Insert'and len(command) ==3:
        print(insert(deck,command))

print(', '.join(deck))
```

And then I translated it to c# using chatGPT since I don't know the language

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> deck = new List<string>(Console.ReadLine().Split(", "));
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string[] command = Console.ReadLine().Split(", ");
            if (command.Length == 2 && command[0] == "Add")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Add(deck, command));
            }
            else if (command.Length == 2 && command[0] == "Remove")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Remove(deck, command));
            }
            else if (command.Length == 2 && command[0] == "Remove At")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(RemoveAt(deck, command));
            }
            else if (command.Length == 3 && command[0] == "Insert")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Insert(deck, command));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", deck));
    }

    static string Add(List<string> deck, string[] command)
    {
        string cardName = command[1];

        if (deck.Contains(cardName))
        {
            return "Card is already in the deck";
        }

        deck.Add(cardName);
        return "Card successfully added";
    }

    static string Remove(List<string> deck, string[] command)
    {
        string cardName = command[1];

        if (deck.Contains(cardName))
        {
            deck.Remove(cardName);
            return "Card successfully removed";
        }

        return "Card not found";
    }

    static string RemoveAt(List<string> deck, string[] command)
    {
        int index = int.Parse(command[1]);

        if (index >= 0 && index < deck.Count)
        {
            deck.RemoveAt(index);
            return "Card successfully removed";
        }

        return "Index out of range";
    }

    static string Insert(List<string> deck, string[] command)
    {
        int index = int.Parse(command[1]);
        string cardName = command[2];

        if (index >= 0 && index <= deck.Count)
        {
            if (deck.Contains(cardName) && index >= 0 && index < deck.Count)
            {
                return "Card is already in the deck";
            }

            deck.Insert(index, cardName);
            return "Card successfully added";
        }

        return "Index out of range";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (deck.Contains(cardName) && index >= 0 && index < deck.Count)` - this looks fishy, because upper clause uses `<=` and you don't need to check it again.

With following input:

```
Ace of Diamonds
1
Insert, 1, Ace of Diamonds
```

It will output:

```
Card successfully added
Ace of Diamonds, Ace of Diamonds
```

Which is incorrect. I belive index check in `insert at` operation should be `index >= 0 && index < deck.Count`. So the full method:

```
static string Insert(List<string> deck, string[] command)
    {
        int index = int.Parse(command[1]);
        string cardName = command[2];

        if (index >= 0 && index < deck.Count)
        {
            if (deck.Contains(cardName))
            {
                return "Card is already in the deck";
            }

            deck.Insert(index, cardName);
            return "Card successfully added";
        }

        return "Index out of range";
    }
}
```

Comment: Before submitting the questiong here, I tried doing so, but it didn't work. NOW... I tried the exact same approach and it worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're not getting the expected result because of the use of the index. In C# arrays start from 0. Meaning, in order to get the first card out of the deck, you need `index = 0`. To get the 7th card you need `index = 6`. You can see that in the example you've given of input and output. On the very first example we can see, that the input doesn't give the index of the array you should put it in, but rather the position in the deck.

`Insert, 2, Jack of Spades`

Clearly, in the output, the **Jack of Spades** is in the 2nd position in the deck, which would be the `[1]` position in the array.

So in order to get the card rigth, you need to always take 1 away from the index number. Example:

```
int index = int.Parse(command[1]);
index--;
```